# Datepicker noweekend and date range

Tags: datepicker

I try to disabled the date for holidays and weekend but that not work 
My code :

```
$(function() {
   $('.thing12DatePicker').datepicker(
        { 
          beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    var startDate = "2017-06-17", 
                    endDate = "2017-06-21",  
                    dateRange = [];           
                            for (var d = new Date(startDate); d <= new Date(endDate); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
                    dateRange.push($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d)&& $.datepicker.noWeekends);
                }
                                var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                                return [dateRange.indexOf(dateString) == -1];
                        }

             });
  });
```

The date holidays are disabled but not the weekend !

I want disbled the weekend .
thx

I have found solution

```
var startDate = "2017-06-17", 
        endDate = "2017-06-21",  
        bankHoliDays = [];
    for (var d = new Date(startDate); d <= new Date(endDate); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)){
                bankHoliDays.push($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d));
            }

function disableDates(date) {

    var dt = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return noWeekend[0] ? (($.inArray(dt, bankHoliDays) < 0) ? [true] : [false]) : noWeekend;
}
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: disableDates
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok i have found

Comment: New problem, if i change the date format (yy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yy ) this code doesn't work . If you have any suggestion

Comment: I have the same problem,  if i change the date format (yy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yy ) this code doesn't work, have you found any solution??